# jquery ui accordion customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to customize a jquery accordion menu.
For tests I used an example into [this page](http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3.1/jquery-ui.html) ( sortable accordion)

I would make sure that when the page is loaded, the menu will remain closed.
At the bottom of page, there are only these settings:

```
//jquery accordion
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                collapsible: true ,
                heightStyle: "content",
                animate: 250,
                header: ".accordion-header"
            }).sortable({
                axis: "y",
                handle: ".accordion-header",
                stop: function( event, ui ) {
                    // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                    // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                    ui.item.children( ".accordion-header" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
                }
            });
```

How can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your options specify:

```
{
  ...
  active: false,
  collapsible: true,
  ...
}
```

See documentation for [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active).